# Integration of Intel SGX and MYsql server

Tags: mysql, sgx, enclave

I am quite new in using Intel SGX, I have a application which uses MySql Server. How can I integrate Intel SGX with Mysql server and how the architecture could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case requires performance, I strongly advise you against trying to shove an entire SQL service into an enclave. Some projects like Gramine make that easy, but in many cases the cost makes it not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it limited to Intel SGX?

To integrate SGX with some libraries, some projects like [Gramine](https://github.com/gramineproject/gramine) and [OpenEnclave](https://github.com/openenclave/openenclave) would be good choices.

An example to run `libsqlite.a` library  in OpenEnclave:
[sqlite](https://github.com/openenclave/openenclave/tree/54f074b14bf8ecc2b4f4902e6d15d721fd533b8d/tests/tools/oeapkman/sqlite) and the used package tool [apkman](https://github.com/anakrish/apkman).

Comment: Thanks so much for you answers, yes it is limited to Intel SGX and I have to integrate MYSQL Server with Intel SGX

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for architecture?

Comment: I mean which parts of MYSQL should be implemented in enclave and how?

Comment: If you integrate Intel SGX with SQL, you have to implement a lot of functionalities that Intel SGX currently does not support. This SQL-SGX project, [EdgelessDB](https://github.com/edgelesssys/edgelessdb), could satisfy your requirements. EdgelessDB is an open-source MySQL-compatible database, runs entirely inside runtime-encrypted Intel SGX enclaves. @sama